# org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Reference to undefined entity: trade

Tags: wcf, soapui, soap-client

I am trying to use SoapUI 5.3.0 for the first time.  Here is what I have done:

1. Created a default WCF Project and published it to IIS.
2. Ensure that I can reach the WSDL here: http://MyComputer/WCFTest/Service1.svc?wsdl
3. Open Soap UI and select File/New SOAP Project
4. Enter the Initial WSDL as per step 2.  The project Name is automatically populated.  Click OK.

Then I see this window:

[image]

I type in my Windows credential (to access the proxy server) and then see this error:

```
Error loading [http://MyComputer/WCFTest/Service1.svc?wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: 
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Reference to undefined entity: trade
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surely in your case there is a problem with authentication through the proxy using *SOAPUI*. Hence *SOAPUI* downloads some error message data instead of the *WSDL*; and this is the reason why you get a `XMLBeans` exception, because `XMLBeans` it's trying to parse and error data instead of an well-formed *WSDL*.

You can try different ways to by-pass this problem:

#### Configure the proxy

You can try to configure correctly the proxy in SOAPUI, access through File > Preference and then select proxy tab on the new window, make sure that your proxy configuration is correct (could be also probably that you're not behind a proxy so a setting to `none` may solve your problem).

[image]

#### Download the WSDL an load in SOAPUI from a file

If you can download the *WSDL* from a browser without problems and you can hit the server endpoint from *SOAPUI*, then simply download the *WSDL* save the file in your disk and create the *SOAPUI* project using the *WSDL* from the file directly.

Comment: Thanks.  Setting Proxy Settings to: None has resolved the problem.  I believe this is because: "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" is selected in Internet Options.

Comment: @w0051977 interesting, anyway nice to help you :)